# Is every codimension one subvariety of a projective variety a set-theoretic complete intersection?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $X$ be a projective variety over $\mathbb C$ and $D\subseteq X$ some subvariety which is pure of codimension one. In fact, in my case $D$ is the complement of an open affine subvariety $U\subseteq X$.

My question is: Is there a single function $f$ in the projective coordinate ring of $X$ such that $D$ is the vanishing set of $f$?

The commutative algebra version of this question would be the following: Given a finitely generated, graded $\mathbb C$-algebra $R$ which is an integral domain and a height one homogeneous prime ideal $\mathfrak p\subseteq R$, is there some $f\in R$ such that $\sqrt{\langle f\rangle}=\mathfrak p$? The Krull Principal Ideal Theorem states in this case that every minimal prime ideal over a (nontrivial) principal ideal is height one, so the question becomes whether each height one prime ideal admits some principal ideal over which it is minimal.

My first instinct would be that it is not true, but I do not know a counterexample.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Take $X$ to be a quadric surface in $\mathbb{P}^3$ and $D$ to be a line on $X$.

Then $D$ has type $(1,0)$ on $X$ (referring to the fact that $Pic(X) = \mathbb{Z}^2$). The only divisors set-theoretically supported on $D$ are multiples of $D$, which have type $(d,0)$. None of these arises as the intersection of $X$ with a hypersurface, since this always results in something of type $(d,d)$.

For an even smaller example, take an elliptic curve in a Weierstrass embedding in $\mathbb{P}^2$ and let $D$ be a non-torsion point. If $P$ is the point at infinity, the embedding of the curve corresponds to the line bundle $\mathcal{O}(3P)$, and no tensor power of this line bundle is isomorphic to a power of $\mathcal{O}(D)$. This is a counterexample in which the complement of $D$ is affine (though of course there are other projective embeddings of the curve in which $D$ is a set-theoretic complete intersection, since $D$ is in particular ample).